# PHP: Understanding @templates annotation with the use of @throws tags

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

I'am using PhpStorm and have started using `@template` annotations.
However, I have trouble understanding exactly how they work in relation to `@throws` tags.

Here are some examples (of fantasy) to explain what I did not understand (or that I am wrong ...).

Let's start with this:

```php
/**
 * A custom ErrorException
 */
class CustomErrorException extends ErrorException {}

/**
 * This class can throw exceptions
 */
class CanThrowExceptions
{
    /**
     * Checks `$value` is `true` or throws `$exception`
     * @template TrueValue
     * @template PassedException as \ErrorException
     * @param TrueValue $value Value you want to check
     * @param class-string<PassedException> $exception
     * @return TrueValue
     * @throws PassedException
     */
    public static function isTrueOrErrorException($value, string $exception = \ErrorException::class)
    {
        if ($value) {
            return $value;
        }

        throw new $exception;
    }
}
```

In other words, the `isTrueOrErrorException` method can throw `$exception`.
`$exception` can be `ErrorException` (default) or another exception that extends `ErrorException` (like `CustomErrorException`).

So far, I believe I have used the `@templates` correctly (**is that right?**).

Now let's try to get PhpStorm to generate some code. I get this result:

```php
class Example
{
    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function test1(): bool
    {
        return CanThrowExceptions::isTrueOrErrorException(true);
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function test2(): bool
    {
        return CanThrowExceptions::isTrueOrErrorException(true, CustomErrorException::class);
    }
}
```

There is no `@throws` tag, when I would expect `ErrorException` for the first method and `CustomErrorException` for the second.

Needless to say, if I try to edit by hand, the IDE will complain and report a problem to me.

I mean, I think I should normally get this (**but this is not the case!**):

```php
class Example
{
    /**
     * @return bool
     * @throws \ErrorException
     */
    public function test1(): bool
    {
        return CanThrowExceptions::isTrueOrErrorException(true);
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     * @throws \CustomErrorException
     */
    public function test2(): bool
    {
        return CanThrowExceptions::isTrueOrErrorException(true, CustomErrorException::class);
    }
}
```

So what have I done wrong so far?

Let's go to complicate the code.
I add the `valueIsIntOrCustomErrorException()` method to the `CanThrowExceptions` class, which is now like this:

```php
class CustomErrorException extends ErrorException {}

/**
 * This class can throw exceptions
 */
class CanThrowExceptions
{
    /**
     * Checks `$value` is an int or throws `CustomErrorException`
     * @template IntValue
     * @param IntValue $value
     * @return IntValue
     */
    public static function valueIsIntOrCustomErrorException($value)
    {
        //This returns a boolean, so I can't return here
        self::isTrueOrErrorException(is_int($value), CustomErrorException::class);

        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * Checks `$value` is `true` or throws `$exception`
     * @template TrueValue
     * @template PassedException as \ErrorException
     * @param TrueValue $value Value you want to check
     * @param class-string<PassedException> $exception
     * @return TrueValue
     * @throws PassedException
     */
    public static function isTrueOrErrorException($value, string $exception = \ErrorException::class)
    {
        if ($value) {
            return $value;
        }

        throw new $exception;
    }
}
```

Yet another oddity. Again, no `@throws` tags for `valueIsIntOrCustomErrorException()` method!
This is strange, because at least here I would have expected it, since it calls the `isTrueOrErrorException()` method.

Still, I keep wondering, where am I wrong?

I add some tests of this new method:

```php
class Example
{
    //Here same `test1 ()` and `test2 ()` as above

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function test3(): int
    {
        return CanThrowExceptions::valueIsIntOrCustomErrorException(1);
    }
}
```

Again, no `@throws` tags (should be `@throws \CustomErrorException`).

Can you help me, with examples or by suggesting corrections to my code? What I did not understand?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you can't use templates in a `@throws` annotation: https://psalm.dev/r/a8849da7d0. Why don't you use just `@throws \ErrorException` in a isTrueOrErrorException description?

Comment: hi @dmitrii this is just an example. Using `@throws \ErrorException`, then another exception passed as a `$exception` parameter will not be recognized correctly

Comment: I see. Sounds like what you're trying to achieve isn't supported yet: https://github.com/vimeo/psalm/issues/6098